# Formatting Code Snippets on Free WordPress.com Account?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, formatting

I've got a WordPress blog on WordPress.com. When posting something I'm including some sample Java code in the `<code` tags, is there any way I can have this formatted better? Such as syntax highlighting and line numbers etc?

An example of what I have is [here](http://jameselsey.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/android-implementing-global-state-share-data-between-activities-and-across-your-application/), even though I have the code tags it doesnt seem to make it any more readable than normal text

Am I limited in choices as I've gone for the free option?

Comment: I assume you mean wordpress.com as "the wordpress site".

Comment: *@hakre*: There you go again with the improper casing of the trademarked term *WordPress*. I know you think it's a statement but it makes you (and the site) look sloppy.

Comment: *@MikeSchinkel*: From what I see in the revision history, I never edited that answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

wordpress.com supports code syntax-highliting.
You can read all about it here: http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/

for your specific example use:

```
[sourcecode language="java"]
package com.jameselsey.domain;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import android.app.Application;

/**
* This is a global POJO that we attach data to which we
* want to use across the application
* @author James Elsey
*
*/
public class GlobalState extends Application
{
private String testMe;

public String getTestMe() {
return testMe;
}
public void setTestMe(String testMe) {
this.testMe = testMe;
}
}
[/sourcecode]
```

Comment: You can use "lang" instead of "language" if you're into the whole brevity thing.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can. It's `[code] *your code here* [/code]` and you can even hint the language: `[code lang="php"]<?php echo 'test'; ?>[/code]`.

This is the method I prefer (quick to write). There seem to be other ways as the following resource explains: [Support: Code » Posting Source Code (wordpress.com)](http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/)